# Bootable CD to backup a hard disk?

Tags: clonezilla, disk-cloning, norton-ghost

There are lots of tools like FoG, G4L, PING, CloneZilla, etc. which allow you to boot from a CD/USB-key and follow some on-screen menus to backup your hard disk to an FTP server, SSH server, or file-share on some other machine.

But [to reduce any possibility of human error when this task is done many times] is it possible to create a customised boot-disk which automatically stores a copy of your HDD image to a specified location?

Comment: Most OSs have the ability to run a script at boot-time, so what you want to do should be possible.

Comment: I did precisely this with Ghost for a older system I had.  Ghost had a command line interface, so it was possible to write a startup BAT file to do everything automatically.  (But it's been so long I've even forgotten what the startup BAT file is named.  And this was on a diskette.  I'm not sure you can SYS a CD.)

Comment: Here's how it was done a few Windows versions back: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootablecd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good guide to creating a bootable custom Linux distribution here:

http://www.phenix.bnl.gov/~purschke/RescueCD/

(including the actual scripts required to compile .iso files from a directory structure where you can edit the final system which will be on the Live CD)

Doing the "ghosting a hard-disk" part is then just a case of running dd (e.g. from /etc/rc.d) and storing the output in a file somewhere, like:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | gzip -c | ssh fileserver "cat > remotefile.img.gz"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could customize a Clonezilla live image to do whatever you want, for example, automate the image to always backup your HDD into a specific partition without all the steps that you must type before execute the task.

For example, everytime you execute a task with Clonezilla live, it tells your something like it just before you type "Y" to confirm the task:

```
Next time you can run this command directly: 
/opt/drb1/sbin/ocs-sr -g auto -e1 auto -e2 -c -r -j2 -p true restoreddisk Monimage-img sda
```

It could be used by you to automate it into your custom Clonezilla live DVD:

[Use your own script and run it on Clonezilla live](http://clonezilla.org/customized-clonezilla-live.php)

This doc describes how to use your own script and run it on clonezilla live

> First, prepare your own program, say, a script "custom-ocs". A sample
>   script file /opt/drbl/samples/custom-ocs, which allows user to use
>   clonezilla live to choose (1) backup the image of /dev/hda1 (or
>   /dev/sda1) to /dev/hda5 (or /dev/sda5) (2) restore image in /dev/hda5
>   (or /dev/sda5) to /dev/hda1 (or /dev/sda1), can be found when you are
>   running clonezilla live (version 1.0.3-20 or later) or in DRBL server
>   (version 1.7.12-1 or later). More examples are available in
>   /opt/drbl/samples/custom-ocs, you can refer to them.
>
> If you edit the script on MS windows, you have to convert the format
>   to Unix format. You can use the command "dos2unix" to convert it to
>   UNIX format. If you do not convert the format, your script won't work
>   on Unix/Linux system.
>
> Remember to add shebang line (#!/bin/bash) in your script to avoid a
>   "Exec format error" issue.  Boot Clonezilla live, enter command
>   prompt, and run "sudo su -" to become root. Mount a working space as
>   /home/partimag. You can use the command "prep-ocsroot" to help you to
>   do that, or use mount command to mount that. E.g. run "mount /dev/sda1
>   /home/partimag" to use /dev/sda1 as the working dir.
>
> Copy the custom-ocs to dir /home/partimag.

```
cd /home/partimag
```

> Run the follow on Clonezilla live command prompt:

```
/opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-iso -g en_US.UTF-8 -k NONE -s -m ./custom-ocs
```

> to create the iso file for CD/DVD. or
>       /opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-live-dev -g en_US.UTF-8 -k NONE -s -c -m ./custom-ocs
>   to create the zip file for USB flash drive.
>
> In the above examples, "-g en_US.UTF-8" means the language will be
>   English, "-k NONE" means won't change the keyboard layout (default is
>   US keyboard). For other options, please run "/opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-iso
>   -h" or "/opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-live-dev -h" to get more info.

Comment: Where can you find these "examples in /opt/drbl/samples/custom-ocs" -- that directory doesn't exist on the clonezilla live-CD.

Comment: I already did it, but it was a long time ago, I can't remember but take a look at another reference: https://raymii.org/cms/p_Customize_Your_Clonezilla_Live_CD